# How to navigate user after Devise sign up to a specific page (dynamic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

could someone help please. I need to pass :course_id parametr to sign up method in order to navigate user to a specific course page.

I've added to the new.html.erb a hidden field

```
<% if params[:course_id]%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :course_id, value: params[:course_id] %>
  <%end%>
```

to navigate user after sign up to a specific course page.

In Registration controller I have:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
    if user.usertype == "student"
      '/education'
    else
      '/platform'
    end
end
```

I also tried:

```
if params[:user][:course_id]
end
```

in def after_sign_up_path_for(user)

But how to pass :course_id to this method? Session?

Answer (score -1):

You can check additional params from the form using params[:user][:course_id]

solution:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  if params[:user][:course_id]
     redirect_to '/course/:id'

  end
end
```

Comment: It would help future readers if you explained a bit what the solution actually is, because it is exactly as the code in the question it seems